# Replace tokens with other words with NLTK in python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

this is my first question.

I've been working in this assignment in which I had to do a Notepad, and then add a lexical analyzer function in it. The goal was to write code in the notepad and then use the lexical analyzer to break it up and categorize it; and for the last part, it had to change the tokenized words categorized as "Identifiers" by Id and the number of Id that it is, and lastly print the code again with this change.

I've achieved almost everything, but this last parto of changing the tokenized words has beeen difficult to me.

`

```
def cmdAnalyze (): 

    Analyze_program = notepad.get(0.0, END)
    Analyze_program_tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(Analyze_program);

    RE_keywords = "auto|break|case|char|const|continue|default|print"
    RE_Operators = "(\++)|(-)|(=)|(\*)|(/)|(%)|(--)|(<=)|(>=)"
    RE_Numerals = "^(\d+)$"
    RE_Especial_Character = "[\[@&!#$\^\|{}\]:;<>?,\.']|\(\)|\(|\)|{}|\[\]|\""
    RE_Identificadores = "^[a-zA-Z_]+[a-zA-Z0-9_]*"
    RE_Headers = "([a-zA-Z]+\.[h])"

    # Categorización de tokens

    notepad.insert(END, "\n ")

    for token in Analyze_program_tokens:
        if (re.findall(RE_keywords, token)):
            notepad.insert(END, "\n " + token + " --------> Palabra clave")
        elif (re.findall(RE_Operators, token)):
            notepad.insert(END, "\n " + token + " --------> Operador")
        elif (re.findall(RE_Numerals, token)):
            notepad.insert(END, "\n " + token + " --------> Número")
        elif (re.findall(RE_Especial_Character, token)):
            notepad.insert(END, "\n " + token + " --------> Carácter especial/Símbolo")
        elif (re.findall(RE_Identificadores, token)):
            notepad.insert(END, "\n " + token + " --------> Identificadores")
        elif (re.findall(RE_Headers, token)):
            notepad.insert(END, "\n " + token + " --------> Headers")

        else:
            notepad.insert(END, "\n " + " Valor desconocido")

    notepad.insert(END, "\n ")
    notepad.insert(END, Analyze_program_tokens)


This is my current output:

>>> print(‘Hello World’)

 >>> --------> Carácter especial/Símbolo
 print --------> Palabra clave
 (‘ --------> Carácter especial/Símbolo
 Hello --------> Identificadores
 World --------> Identificadores
 ’) --------> Carácter especial/Símbolo
 >>> print (‘ Hello World ’)
```

`

The last line output has to be like this: ">>> print (‘ Id1 Id2 ’)"

Thank you for reading :)

Answer (score 0):

I would add

```
id_count = 0
```

just before the `for` loop, and then modify the handling of identifiers like this:

```
elif (re.findall(RE_Identificadores, token)):
    id_count += 1
    notepad.insert(END, "\n " + f"Id{id_count:02d}' + " --------> Identificadores")
```

**EDIT**

On second thoughts, what happens if an identifier occurs more than once in the notepad? "hello, hello world" should result in "Id01, Id01 Id02" or in "Id01, Id02 Id03"?

In the first case you will need a dictionary. So before the `for` loop let's also add

```
ids = {}
```

and use the dictionary like this

```
elif (re.findall(RE_Identificadores, token)):
    if token not in ids:
        id_count += 1
        ids[token] = id_count
    notepad.insert(END, "\n " + f"Id{ids[token]:02d}' + " --------> Identificadores")
```